How to keep tabs in VS Code all the time
If you open a file with the menu "open with -> Visual Studio Code" when VS Code is was closed, then the previously opened tabs are lost, how can you make them stay open?

Usually, VS Code will retain your tabs if you close it properly.
I've looked and can't seem to find a specific setting, so I'm assuming this is the issue:

Either you're not closing Code properly so it doesn't save your tabs.
Or you are opening a file through your system file manager using VS Code.

It's probably the second one - if you click 'open with Code' through your file manager, it will open a new instance of VS Code. This means that your other tabs and the workspace (file view) will not be visible.
What should happen is that it opens two windows - your old workspace and tabs, as well as a new window with the file you wanted in.
Try this:

Open VS Code and open some files in that window (ctrl + o).
Close the window with alt + f4.
Find a file on your computer and use the 'open with code' option to open a new VS Cod(ium) instance.

You should see that two windows open - your old tabs, then another window with the new file.
I hope this helps, feel free to ask me for more info :)

I think have understand how to keep tabs open in VS Code,  need to open VS Code first and then open new files. If you open files using the "open with" menu, the tabs are lost. Thank you :)

@Besha No problem, let me know if you need any more help!
